# Merge multiple lines to single line in a file skipping the header

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have several 1000s of files in a folder. Each file has contents as shown below. My filename in this example is: AAB08704.1.fasta

```
   >gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
   MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTE
   VHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILI
   PARIH
```

I want to skip the first line and then merge the remaining lines into a single line. All my files begin with ">" which is the header information and the following lines are the sequence information which I want to merge into a single line.

I tried

```
    sed -i '2,$s/\n//g' AAB08704.1.fasta
```

I even tried converting multiline fasta to single line fasta using:

```
   awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' < AAB08704.1.fasta
```

both these commands don't do what I expect. Any leads?

Expected output:

```
   >gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
   MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
```

cat -A AAB08704.1.fasta gives this:

```
  M-oM-;M-?>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]^M$
  MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTE^M$
  VHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILI^M$
```

Comment: Now added my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n// if $. > 1 && !eof' AAB08704.1.fasta 
>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
```

- `s/\n//` remove newline

  - `if $. > 1 && !eof` only if line number is greater than one and not end of file
- Use `perl -i -pe` for inplace editing. See [Command Switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for documentation on `-i`, `-p` and `-e`

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't replace the new line characters. I still get the same output as my input file. Looks like there is a formatting problem with my file. Any leads to force the substitution?

Comment: can you paste output of `cat -A AAB08704.1.fasta` to question? I think your file may have `\r\n` instead of `\n` for line endings

Comment: Yes, added now.

Comment: to take care of dos style  line ending, use `perl -pe 's/\r//; s/\n// if $. > 1 && !eof'` ... but not sure about the initial `M-oM-;M-?`

Comment: Thank you. this looks great to replace the ^M and for M-oM-;M-? 
i found this: `sed -e '1 s/^.//' file`

Comment: you can also use `perl -pe 's/\r//; s/^.// if $. == 1; s/\n// if $. > 1 && !eof'` to use single command only...

Answer (score 0):

Like this? For GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{p=p $0 (FNR==1?ORS:"")}ENDFILE{print p;p=""}' file file
>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
```

This one removes all chars before `>`on the first record:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{sub(/^[^>]*/,"");p=$0 ORS;next}{p=p $0}ENDFILE{print p;p=""}' file file
>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta]
MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
```

Comment: Not typo, simulating multiple files with just one.

Comment: @Sundeep It prints the `file` twice on purpose because the `file` is mentioned twice after the awk code. OP begins with: _I have several 1000s of files_ and I assumed @biobudhan does not want to process the files one at the time therefore my solution processes all the files given as a parameter. However, there was no requirement on the output (each output to separate file or such) so it outputs everything to stdout. If you test other solutions to the question they most likely fail if given more files to process at once so they need to be run inside a shell loop.

Comment: oh ok, didn't catch on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

sed is line oriented, so need to load line in buffer than remove `\n`

```
sed -i -e '1d' -e 'H;${x;s/\n//g}' AAB08704.1.fasta
```

awk could be adapted in behavior

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="()";OFS=""}{$1="";$0=$0 ""}' AAB08704.1.fasta > tmp && mv tmp AAB08704.1.fasta

# or 
awk '!a++{next}{printf( "%s", $0) > (FILENAME ".tmp")}' AAB08704.1.fasta && mv AAB08704.1.fasta.tmp AAB08704.1.fasta
# or
awk 'NR>1{printf("%s",$0)}' AAB08704.1.fasta > tmp && mv tmp AAB08704.1.fasta
```

Comment: The awk approach just deletes the contents of my file.

Comment: sorry for the awk, i just mix 2 version of code (RS used in second version). adapted

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS = "" }/^>/{ print $0, "\n"}NR>1{ print $0 }' file
```

Output:

```
>gi|1117824|gb|AAB08704.1| ecdysteroid regulated 16 kDa [Manduca sexta] 
MLFYITVTVLLVSAQAKFYTDCGSKLATVQSVGVSGWPENARECVLKRNSNVTISIDFSPTTDVSAITTEVHGVIMSLPVPFPCRSPDACKDNGLTCPIKAGVVANYKTTLPVLKSYPKVSVDVKWELKKDEEDLVCILIPARIH
```